# how to generate all possible 3 digit combination of the numbers 0-6

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel and am trying to generate a table (3 columns) that presents all possible combinations of the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5, and 6. Digits are allowed to be repeated (example, 2-2-5). To do that manually it will take forever and frankly speaking, I'm not an expert here and was not able to solve this by my own.

In other words, each row would have three digits each placed on a separate cell; but three of them represent one possible combination of the digits 0-6. I need to have all the possible combinations. I have been looking allot for this but unfortunately couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This small macro will get your data:

```vb
Sub qwerty()
    For i = 0 To 6
        For j = 0 To 6
            For k = 0 To 6
                LL = LL + 1
                Cells(LL, 1) = i
                Cells(LL, 2) = j
                Cells(LL, 3) = k
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: thanks for that explanation, but what if you cannot repeat ?

Comment: @user450067 ...........I don't understand your question...........once the workbook has been save with the macro, you should ALWAYS be able to repeat it.