# How to generate all possibilities of combination for a set of values or range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Reference to question and answer below, 
[how to generate all possible 3 digit combination of the numbers 0-6](https://superuser.com/questions/808243/how-to-generate-all-possible-3-digit-combination-of-the-numbers-0-6?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have similar case (need to generate all possible combinations) but for set of values like in table below, total possibilities will be 16807 combinations

```
A   B   C   D   E
54  23  43  1   1
21  45  433 5   51
25  65  456 3   3
65  66  5678    100 5
12  77  980 5   6
13  90  878 6   66
111 909 662 50  55
```

Combinations will look like

```
A   B   C   D   E
54  23  43  1   1
54  23  43  1   51
54  23  43  1   3
54  23  43  1   5
54  23  43  1   6
54  23  43  1   66
54  23  43  1   55
54  23  43  5   1
54  23  43  5   51
54  23  43  5   3
54  23  43  5   5
54  23  43  5   6
54  23  43  5   66
54  23  43  5   55

…               
…               
111 909 662 50  55
```

Manually it will take forever and frankly speaking, I'm not an expert in Excel.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you clarify how you get 16807? C(35,5) is 324632.

Comment: How this different from your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/960188/how-to-generate-all-possibilities-of-combination-for-a-set-of-number-or-range)?

Answer (score 0):

Running this short macro:

```
Sub Combin()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim nRow As Long
    nRow = 1
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To 7
      ii = .Cells(i, "A").Value
      For j = 1 To 7
        jj = .Cells(j, "B").Value
        For k = 1 To 7
          kk = .Cells(k, "C").Value
          For l = 1 To 7
            ll = .Cells(l, "D").Value
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nRow, "A").Value = ii
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nRow, "B").Value = jj
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nRow, "C").Value = kk
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nRow, "D").Value = ll
            nRow = nRow + 1
          Next l
        Next k
      Next j
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

will take data on *Sheet1* like:

[image]

and produce data like:

[image]

on *Sheet2* for all **2401** combinations.